# How do I check a 3x3 tictactoe board for empty spaces? What I have so far is not running

Tags: javascript

```
 // Check if there are any empty cells (boxes) on the board,
  // if so the game is in progress. Otherwise, the game is
 // over and is a tie.
 // YOUR CODE HERE
 for(var row = 0;row < board.length; row++){
  for(var column = 0; column< board[row].length; column++){
  if (board[row][column]===' '){
    return '?'
  }else{
    return '-' ;
  }
}
```

}
}
    I'm not exactly sure how this code should be written, and I don't even know what to google to learn how to check for empty boxes/cells.

Comment: please specify what you like to do with the result. if you are looking inly for one empty space, or more, or if like to return the position aka indices?

Comment: What is `board`? Also if you can share a working snippet, it would really help.

Comment: Hi Nina, I'm not looking for indices. I'm supposed to return "?" if there happen to be empty spaces on the board. I just don't know what code to write that finds the empty space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return a value in both branches of the if-else structure. I would try something like:

```
function hasEmptyCells(board) {
    for(var row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for(var row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            if(board[row][column]===' '){
                return true; //or you can return "?", but I don't see why that would be better
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //or, again you could return "-" too
}
```

This way if you find an empty space, you can return immediately, but if you don't, you have to loop through all the cells to make sure none of them are empty and thus return the value only after the loops finished.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in a nested way for the given board. It returns `true` if the first empty space is found.

```js
function hasSpace(board) {
    return board.some(row => row.some(item => item === ' '));
}

var emptyBoard = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']],
    fullBoard = [['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X']];

console.log(hasSpace(emptyBoard));
console.log(hasSpace(fullBoard));
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: I did not understand the context of the question, and the other comment did a pretty good job at answering your question. I'll leave this tip, though.

As a beginner in Javascript, I recommend you to use the console commands to print to console. There you will see errors and exceptions. To open the developer console in chrome, hit F12 (or right-click>inspect anywhere in the page, then click console).

Please note you tried returning multiple values, while not in function. I assume you meant to print them, and see what is in the array. To do this, you can simply do:

```
for(var row = 0;row < board.length; row++){
  for(var column = 0; column< board[row].length; column++){
    if (board[row][column]===' '){
      console.log('?')
    }else{
      console.log('-')
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note you can use console.log to see the contents of board itself, like so: console.log(board).

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I'm actually working in a large function .getResults where I find the where X or O wins and for another part I'm responding to blank spaces. I am just so new to this that I don't know how to upload the info. sorry.

Comment: In that case, you may want to upload a bigger part of your code, to understand the full context of the question.